# Safari seems to not support CSP nonces on link tags being used to preload JS

Tags: safari, content-security-policy

I'm using Safari 14.0.3 on Mac, and rendering the following link tag:

```html
<link rel="preload" href="/_next/static/chunks/194.js?ts=1619710448027" as="script" nonce="Hkb65_tcgqVrk2Zk">
```

My CSP header includes the following:

```
script-src 'strict-dynamic' 'unsafe-eval' 'nonce-Hkb65_tcgqVrk2Zk';
```

As you can see, the correct nonce is being applied to the link tag. This works correctly in Chrome and FF, but Safari throws the error:

> [Error] [Report Only] Refused to load https://dev.example.com:4200/_next/static/chunks/194.js?ts=1619710448027 because it does not appear in the script-src directive of the Content Security Policy.

I haven't been able to find anything online about Safari failing to support nonces on `link` tags. Hoping someone can tell me how to solve this or point me to resources that at least confirm it isn't possible.

Comment: Adding `'self'` to the CSP `script-src` directive does let it work on Safari, but I'd prefer to avoid this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Safari does not support `'nonce-value'` for the `<link rel="preload"` construction. BTW, the Firefox browser - too, it allows preloading resourses even without `'nonce-value'`. Only Chrome support nonces in preloading scripts and styles.

You needlessly fear the use of the `'self'` token - it [is cancelled](https://csplite.com/csp/test217/#conclusions) when paired with `'strict-dynamic'` token in CSP3 browsers (modern Chrome and Firefox). Therefore `'self'` will only work in Safari which does not support `'strict-dynamic'`.
I think you found a good decision for the issue - to use CSP in browsers backward compatibility mode.

Comment: Interesting! I assume Firefox is preloading of the assets isn't actually a security risk because the assets don't get executed. Does that sound right to you?

Comment: Yes, preloaded scripts don't get executed, and styles - don't get applied. Therefore Firefox's behaviour looks safe. But I can't figure out is it intention behaviour or Firefox just unsupported nonces for the `<link rel='preload'`.